# download images from cloudinary via api

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

how can I download images from cloudinary ?

I list my ressource then I create a zip file, and then ? I dont understand the process

```
  cloudinary.v2.api.resources()
  .then((res => {
    
    res.resources.map((el => {
      cloudinary.v2.uploader
      .create_zip({tags: 'PDF', public_ids: el.public_id})
      .then(result=>console.log(result));
    
      }))
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Cloudinary CLI is a good choice here:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudinary_cli#sync

> The sync command synchronizes between a local folder and a Cloudinary
> folder, maintaining the folder structure.
>
> Syntax cld [cli options] sync [command options] local_folder
> cloudinary_folder

Try this with the "--pull" option to download a directory to your local desktop.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily add images in Cloudinary

```
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
cloudinary.config({
cloud_name: "####bqa",
api_key: "########8978",
api_secret: "#########6bs",
secure: true,
});
```

this is the uploader controller

```
exports.uploadUsertImage = async (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.body;
file = req.files.profileimage;
if (!id) return next(new AppErr("Pelase Provide vehicle Id"), 200);
cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.tempFilePath, async (err, result) => {
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
user.profilePicture = result.url;
await user.save();
res.status(200).json({
  status: true,
  data: {
    message: "Upload User Image Successfully",
    },
   });
 });
};
```

try it to download

you'll get Cloudinary's [upload response](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#upload_response) which contains all necessary data to save on your end such as the resource's `public_id`, `version for immediate cache busting. These parameters can be then used for further [manipulation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_manipulation#direct_url_building).

You also get the resource's `url` and `secure_url` (https) ready for delivery.